# In c++, declaring class variable as private is always good?

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

In Java, usually, it is recommended to declare class variable as `private`.
I wonder C++ also is, like Java. But if it is, the problem is though (as I think), most class should have `get()`, `set()` functions and i think is quite bothering. But if it is good programming habits, I gonna follow it. Please share your opinion.

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want. If you want a C-style struct style, with access to the raw data, then that isn't what you want. If you want to do some other operation on set or get, setters/getters is the way to go.

Comment: It always depends. For example, `std::stack<T>` has a `protected` data member.

Comment: what about in embedded system? give me advices please.

Comment: Declaring class members as private isn't good java design, its *good object oriented* design. You want to encapsulate as much of the functionality of your class as possible. 

The more functions you write that access your private members, the less encapsulated your class is. That isn't a dire warning against creating functions, it just means don't "automatically" create accessor and mutator  functions.

Comment: Two sides to embedded. One is small and fast to overcome the limits of the platform. The other is never ever crashes. Slow sucks, but if the autopilot crashes, the plane may follow. That's generally considered really, really bad. To me, encapsulation is about self-defense. Each object defends it's state with well written getters and setters for data that needs to be shared and not sharing the data that doesn't. Start with paranoia and lock down everything. Execution will tell you if something's too slow and profiler will tell you if it's how you armoured accessors. Until then, err to private.

Comment: It's completely ok to have public variables as long as they don't bother you

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are talking about is called encapsulation. Now, with that term, you should be able to find proper definitions but you should also be able to find reasons for its use. Once you gained an understanding of the reasons for encapsulation, you will be able to weigh its costs and benefits for solving the task you have and thus decide whether to use it or not.

BTW, these principles are completely independent of the programming language you use, although they may take different forms in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

If your `class` is merely a collection of data members like a C `struct`, then it may be best to stick with `public` members.

However, a C++ `class` is much more powerful than a C `struct`. In particular, it has a `public` interface which is exposed to the user and a `private` part, which aids the implementation of the public interface, but is hidden from the user. In this way, the private interface can be altered without affecting the usability of the class.

Getters and Setters are not necessarily part of the public interface.

Answer (score 0):

What you talk about, you may know, is called Encapsulation. It has several advantages.

Let's say you have a class to get the temperature from a sensor every X seconds. You will certainly have a variable which contains the temperature. If your variable is public then everybody can write

```
std::cout << "temperature is : " << temperatureReader.temperature << " °C";
```

But if the sensor change and return a temperature in farenheit, you're in trouble. If you had created a getters for this class, your only change would have been in the getters, convert your farenheit in celsius. But with a public variable have to refactor a LOT of code. then a Getter is important.

Let's say now you have in your class a connector to the sensor. If it is public everybody can write :

```
temperatureReader.sensor = nullptr;
```

Sure it is evil but I can do it, remember that your classes have to be easy to use efficiently and hard to use badly. But if you had created a Setters, you would have been able to control what goes in your variable.

There's also one important thing about OOP, the SOLID principles :

Public variable are also inherited by your children class, you may not that.